# thrift server - hive contexts - load/update data from spark code

Tags: apache-spark, hive, thrift

Does the ThriftServer create its own HiveContext?

My aim is to create tables/load data from spark code (spark-submit) by HiveContext such that clients of thriftServer will be able to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, of course it creates context:
[Thrift Code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive-thriftserver/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/thriftserver/SparkSQLEnv.scala)

But I have seen strange issue - it looks like hive context is cached on starting of thrift server. If I run some other app which creates/changes hive table, thrift server doesn't see the changes. Only restarting the service helps